# How to deploy Node.js & Express.js Backend to be used by Next.js Frontend via Vercel?

Tags: node.js, next.js, backend, hosting, vercel

ho guys, i want to deploy my next.js application to vercel. well there's no problem about that. But for the reason of a scalable application i have my used backend written separately in Node.js. I also want this to be used with the Next.js Frontend preferably by hosting it on vercel.

So is this possible by default? I don't understand how to achieve this and what will be the necessary steps after having the backend, say, deployed on vercel.

Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you checked https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel?

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately you cannot host a backend on Vercel. If you want to host a backend simply you should look at Heroku or Railway. You should then be able to connect your Vercel frontend to your backend hosted by Heroku or Railway

Comment: Sure you can: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions